# Can I run play and start server using batch file from command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, playframework

Play version 2.1.1

The problem I encounter is I try to run the server within the play console and I don't know if I can do it from the batch file.

```
    C:\
cd C:\dev\work\npadmin\trunk
path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;%PATH%
C:\play-2.1.1\play debug
call run -Dnameprofiler.graph.path=c:/nameprofiler-data/graph2/graph_2015-07-14_08-00-00/ono.db -Dnameprofiler.datapath=c:/nameprofiler-data -Ddataloading=lazy
```

Up until play debug, everything is fine, I get in the console but I have no output of the 'run' within the console.

```
    ...
play! 2.1.1 (using Java 1.7.0_79 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

[npadmin] $
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: All the documentation I see says to run this from activator.bat. I don't know what the 'play' executable does, or how to get its usage. Your batch input starting with `call run` wouldn't get to the prompt that `play` creates. It looks like if you use activator, you'd skip the `call` and `run`parts and put the rest of those arguments after `activator --jvm-debug` instead of running `play debug`

Comment: @LinuxDisciple this is play 2.1.1, an older version that does not use the activator.bat.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I found a way to enter the debug and run the play app.. it is way too simple.

use 'play debug' and the 'run YOUR_CODE' in the same like:

```
C:\play-2.1.1\play debug run -Dnameprofiler.graph.path=c:/nameprofiler-data/graph2/graph_2015-07-14_08-00-00/ono.db -Dnameprofiler.datapath=c:/nameprofiler-data -Ddataloading=lazy
```

Somehow it forces it into play's command and works.